# My widget not printing before_widgets and after widgets

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am facing problems with the sidebar widgets.I have registered sidebar and used wp default sidebars but it is neither within its container div not printing `before_widget` and `after_widget`

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_sidebar_widget' );
function my_sidebar_widget(){
    register_sidebar( array(
       'name'           => __('Home Page Sidebar', 'nefar'),
       'id'             => 'sidebar-1',
       'before_widget'  => '<div class="sidebar-block">', 
       'before_widget'  => '</div>', 
       'before_title'   => '<h4 class="sidebar-heading">',
       'after_title'    => '</h4>',
    ));  
}
```

### And the index.php codes are here

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?php
                if(have_posts()){
                    while(have_posts()){
                        the_post();
                        ?>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php
                dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1');
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

### And on output page source code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <h3>The 15 Secrets That You Shouldn&#8217;t Know About Toys.</h3>
                                                <h3>eMusic’s owners believe they can convince users start buying songs again</h3>
                                                <h3>Twitter invokes the allure of one of its biggest users for its billboard ads</h3>
                                                <h3>Spring Asparagus with Creamy Burrata &#038; Pesto</h3>
                                                <h3>Falling Leaves: Endearing Portraits of a Grandmother, a Grandson</h3>
                            </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        </div><h4 class="sidebar-heading">Search</h4><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/">
            <div>
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </form></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

I Don't know whre the  is coming from after the widget and the widget is outside `col-md-4`

Comment: In your code no after widgets. Two time before widgets. Please change it and try one again.

Answer (score 1):

first add this code to functions.php

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Top Footer', 'educate'),
        'id' => 'top-footer',
        'description' => __('Top Full width footer.', 'educate'),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="footer-widget %2$s" id="%1$s" >',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="footer-widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
```

after add this code where you want to show widget

```
       <?php if (is_active_sidebar('top-footer')) {

        if (is_active_sidebar('top-footer')) {
                        echo '<aside class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">';
                        dynamic_sidebar('top-footer');
                        echo '</aside>';
                    }


        } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You make some mistake. Use this:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_sidebar_widget' );
function my_sidebar_widget(){
    register_sidebar( array(
       'name'           => __('Home Page Sidebar', 'nefar'),
       'id'             => 'sidebar-1',
       'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s sidebar-block">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h4 class="sidebar-heading">',
    'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_sidebar_widget' );

    function my_sidebar_widget(){
        register_sidebar( array(
           'name'           => __('Home Page Sidebar', 'nefar'),
           'id'             => 'sidebar-1',
           'before_widget'  => '<div class="sidebar-block">', 
           'after_widget'  => '</div>', 
           'before_title'   => '<h4 class="sidebar-heading">',
           'after_title'    => '</h4>',
        ));  
    }
```

I hope is useful.